# ExactTarget: Target list id [myTestList] is invalid

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying this REST request:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \-d '{"TargetListIds":["myTestList"],"OverrideTemplateTargetLists": "true","OverrideTemplateExclusionLists": "false","IgnoreExclusionLists": "true","OverrideMessageText": "true","MessageText" : "Hello from xxxxxx","BlackoutWindow": {"UtcOffset": "-0100","WindowStart": "2100","WindowEnd": "2200"},"AllowDuplication": "false"}' https://www.exacttargetapis.com/sms/v1/messageList/xxxxxxxxx/send?access_token=xxxxxxxxx
```

I have tried different list Id/names but constantly I am getting this error.

```
Target list id [myTestList] is invalid.
```

While I am able to send message successfully when sending direct to phone nos (array of Nos.). I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

I read some where that salesforce stopped SMS API send service which seems not correct as its only not working when you sending to List/DE.

Comment: Do you get this error if you use a valid Id?

Comment: Yes, I am getting same error with valid Id